# creating beamer themes with options

Tags: beamer, optional-arguments, themes

Is it possible to create beamer themes that take options?  I have three themes that are essentially the same yet each `beamertheme<name>.sty`  overrides certain aspects of the inner, outer and color themes.

I want to be able to do something like

```
\usetheme{mytheme}[default]
```

or

```
\usetheme{mytheme}[sidebar]
```

where some options of the theme change depending upon what you call.  Is this possible?  If so can someone point me to an example.

Comment: Hi Robin, [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I edited your post slightly to make bits of code stand out. Inline code uses back ticks and block code is simply indented.

Answer (score 10):

Thank you for the suggestion.  I had looked once before and found nothing. More success this time though.

In my beamerthememytheme.sty I have to add the following lines at the beginning:

```
\newif\if@doMyOption
\@doMyOptionfalse
\DeclareOption{myoption}{\@doMyOptiontrue}
\ProcessOptions
```

In the same file I can then add the lines:

```
\if@doMyOption
Things to do if true
\else
Things to do if false
\fi
```

Then when I use the sty file I do

```
\usetheme[myoption]{mytheme}
```

Answer (score 5):

The [Beamer manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) explains that some themes have options. You can look how these options are used inside the theme declaration file.

Just as an example, the [`rounded` innertheme](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemerounded.sty) has an option `shadow`.