# How to create a colour option in custom beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, color, optional-arguments, themes

I have used [this answer from the question about how to design a beamer theme from scratch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146682/54029) to design a Beamer theme to look like a university presentation (Powerpoint) template. There are 3 colour options for the Powerpoint template (blue,green,slate). I know one option for a solution would be to create 3 separate colour themes and to just call them with;

```
\usecolortheme{mythemeblue}
\usecolortheme{mythemegreen}
\usecolortheme{mythemeslate}
```

What I would like to do though is to define all the different colours in one colortheme file and then be able to use an option to call them as follows

```
\usetheme[blue]{mytheme}  %or green or slate
```

I have seen questions on the site that seem to use `\DeclareOption` ([at this question, but couldn't get to work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38761/54029)) or `\DeclareOptionBeamer` ([This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51658/54029) & [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240037/54029) - didn't really understand these solutions)

Ideally what I would like is a solution where I can define differently in the `beamercolorthememytheme.sty` the same colour names depending on what option was chosen. For example if option blue was chosen Beamer would know that `\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{104,7,90}` but if option green was chosen it would know that `\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{81,139,36}` etc

Hopefully this is enough info but if not let me know in the comments

This is what I have in my `beamercolorthememytheme.sty`

```
\mode<presentation>

% define colours from NUIG stylesheet
\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{104,7,90}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB}{27,65,99}
\definecolor{col3}{RGB}{138,167,147}
\definecolor{col4}{RGB}{143,183,195}
\definecolor{col5}{RGB}{194,230,242}
% set colours for different elements
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=col3!100!col4}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=col4,fg=col2}
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=col5}
\setbeamercolor*{subtitle}{fg=col5}
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=col5}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=col5}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=col5}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=col1,fg=col5}
\mode
<all>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example shows how to change the colour of the frame title conditionally. `blue` will be used as the default colour, in case no option is specified.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[style=blue]{mytheme}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{test}
        abc
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

with the corresponding `beamerthememytheme.sty`, which does little more than just pass the colour option to the colour theme.

```
\mode<presentation>

\DeclareOptionBeamer{style}{
    \PassOptionsToPackage{style=#1}{beamercolorthememytheme}
}
\ExecuteOptionsBeamer{style=blue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\usecolortheme{mytheme}

\mode
<all>
```

and the colour theme `beamercolorthememytheme.sty`:

```
\mode<presentation>

\DeclareOptionBeamer{style}{\def\beamer@mytheme@style{#1}}
\ExecuteOptionsBeamer{style=blue} % blue will be default if nothing is given
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\def\beamer@mytheme@stylegreen{green}%
\def\beamer@mytheme@styleblue{blue}%
\def\beamer@mytheme@stylered{red}%

\ifx\beamer@mytheme@style\beamer@mytheme@stylegreen%
    \definecolor{col1}{RGB}{0,255,0} % green
\else% 
    \ifx\beamer@mytheme@style\beamer@mytheme@stylered%
        \definecolor{col1}{RGB}{255,0,0} % red
    \else% 
      \definecolor{col1}{RGB}{0,0,255} % blue
    \fi%
\fi%

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=white,fg=col1}

\mode
<all>
```

[image]

Comment: This works great but when I try to define a third option I can't get the 3 options to work. Does the code have to be different for a third option to apply?

Comment: @gman see the edit

Comment: Perfect; I was missing the extra `\else%` and `\fi%` when trying to add a third option. All working fine now.